# Ping in linux script with case

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

In Linux I use a script to ping a couple of addresses.
Now I want that the user can do: `bash Script 50-60`
And that the script pings the addresses 192.168.100.50 - 192.168.100.60
I use xx-yy to do this and I tried but the part after the `shift` is wrong.

```
for i in $*;
do
case $* in
 "XX-YY" ) shift;
           ping -c 1 192.168.0.$1 - $i
done
```

Comment: `"XX-YY"` is a literal string.I don't understand why you would be using shift or a loop either, the range is surely from one number to another unless you want to pass the args as pairs ?

Comment: no i want that the they do "bash script.sh XX-YY 50-60 " like u can use -c or -h and give something else with it

Answer (score 3):

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=${1%-*}
end=${1#*-}
for ((i=start;i<=end;i++));do
    ping -c 1 192.168.0.$i
done
```

Usage:

```
bash path_to_the_Script 50-60
```

A little explanation:

I used [bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to extract `start` and `end` from the input string `50-60`.

`${1#*-}` is the string after the first match of a `-` in `$1`

and

`${1%-*}` is the string before the last match (first match from right) of a `-` in `$1`

Comment: Your solution is quite handy. With an explanation it will be great!

Comment: How can I make a function of this to use in a case?

Comment: @gladius put the code inside a function declaration, like this: `functionname(){copypastecodewithoutshebang}` and use it with `functionname 50-60`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this logic:
ping 192.168.100.{50..60}

Comment: note the `{A..B}` expression does not work with variables, so you will probably have to use some kind of `seq` to create this output.

Comment: I know ;) But it is for something for school that we must use that.